# Предложение составлено корректно?

Tags: синтаксис

Нижеприведенное предложение составлено корректно?

> Лишен избирательных прав 29 марта 1931 г. как зажиточный крестьянин
> ("кулак").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется, что все правильно в этом предложении (слово [*кулак*](http://endic.ru/kuzhecov/Kulak-62861.html) общеизвестно, использовано в прямом значении, поэтому кавычки, думаю, не нужны).

Мы не капиталисты, не помещики, не фабриканты, не кулаки. [В. П. Катаев. Алмазный мой венец (1975-1977)]

[лише́ние](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&all=x)
**1.** К **лишить** и **лишиться**. *Лишение свободы. Лишение избирательных прав.*

[лишить](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C), -шу, -шишь; лишённый; -шён, -шена, -шено; ***св.** кого-что, кого-чего.*
**1. *(нсв. лишать).*** Оставить без кого-либо, чего-либо, отнять что-либо у кого-либо. *Лишить свободы. Лишить наследства. Лишить возможности заниматься спортом. Лишить слова* (не дать возможности высказаться на собрании, митинге и т.п.; прервать выступление).

*Лишен* (чего? Р. п., мн. ч.) *прав.*
Существует *активное* избирательное право (право голосовать, избирать) и *пассивное* (быть избранным), поэтому — "прав" (мн. ч.).

По этой причине он был лишен избирательных прав. [Б. Е. Черток. Ракеты и люди (1999)]

Да, он был лишен избирательных прав, но подал заявление и надеется, что его восстановят. [С. М. Голицын. Записки уцелевшего (1980-1989)]

*85 лет назад, в 1926 году, ЦИК СССР принял новую инструкцию о выборах в советы, **лишавшую значительную часть населения страны избирательных прав*** ([из статьи](https://www.kommersant.ru/doc/1821767)).